# SSRS Scheduling: Spaces in a path

Tags: reporting-services, path, ssrs-2012

I am trying to schedule a report to export to a path. Because the path contains spaces it gives an error "Failure writing file" "Could not find a part of the path" and I am not sure what to replace spaces with.

This is the path

\SOME PATH\Folder1\Folder2\EXPORT HERE

I tried this and did not work.

\SOME+PATH\Folder1\Folder2\EXPORT+HERE

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Report Manager's **Subscriptions**? I have spaces in my folder names and don't have a problem with them. Are you using a network location? You don't have two slashes at the beginning for the domain. I'm using something like: `\\domain\files\PROD\Member\Reports\Archive Month End`

Comment: using two slashes fixed it. Thanks!